# Extracting 2 numbers from a 1 to 4 digit number

Tags: objective-c

Here is what I need to do:

I am given an int that is from 0 to 9999.

What I need to do is imagine that this int is 0 padded to 4 digits:

```
4 -> 0004
675 -> 0675
etc
```

I need to then extract the first 2 digits into an int and the last 2 into an int:

```
4 -> (0,4)
675 -> (6,75)
8976 -> (89,76)
```

I'm just not sure how to go about doing this in obj-C.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int initial = 4;

int first = initial / 100; // will be 0
int second = initial % 100; // will be 4

int initial = 8976;

int first = initial / 100; // will be 89
int second = initial % 100; // will be 76
```

Comment: @Jeremy How else would you do it?

Comment: @rmaddy I can imagine variant with converting to string, padding, splitting and converting back to int :)

Comment: @rmaddy By adding more complexity and unnecessary code.